# Jenkins javac argument

Tags: jenkins, command-line-arguments, javac

I need to set a java compiler argument using maven.  I can't seem to find where Jenkins calls the Java compiler for me to add an argument.

If someone could shed some light on where I would set this?

Thank, Jake

---

So I found out that javac arguments are set in the project's POM via a plugin.  Eg. below:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <compilerArgument>-verbose -bootclasspath ${java.home}\lib\rt.jar</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Please provide some details on how do you build your job and how `javac` is called. Do you use an *Invoke Ant*, *Invoke Maven target* or another step? If you use *Execute shell* and call `javac` from there, adding arguments should be straightforward :)

Comment: I'm using Maven.  From my understanding it uses Maven to sort and grab dependencies before passing on the source to the Java compiler.  I have setup JVM arguments in my POM and that works fine but need to set javac arguments.  I'm not sure how javac is called, I thought this was something Jenkins took care of from knowing the JAVA_HOME.  A lot of assumptions have been made! Please correct me if I'm way off here! Thanks for the swift reply.

Comment: Thanks. You should edit your question so the next person doesn't have to look for clarification in the comments. Unfortunately I don't know `maven` (I use `ant`), but I suppose that Jenkins only calls `maven` and `maven` calls `javac`. I would guess that you can set `javac` in `pom.xml`. However, you probably should wait for an answer from somebody who knows `maven`.

Comment: Thanks, you were correct, it is set in the POM via a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

With Maven 3.6 the answer could be to configure this in your projects `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-verbose</arg>
            <arg>-bootclasspath ${java.home}\lib\rt.jar</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See [**Apache Maven Compiler Plugin** documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/), [`compile:compile` goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs), and [*Pass Compiler Arguments* example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html).